# R building list of lists with lapply and adding in a name

Tags: r, csv

I'm using parLapply to read lots of small CSV files. Then running table() to tabulate the results and put them in a list of lists.  into the parLapply function I pass in the id/csv file name.

`ll <- parLapply(ids, function(id){
  df<-read.csv(paste0(id,".csv"))
  return(table(df$result))})`

However the names of the list is lost `( names(ll) returns NULL )`.  How can I get the names for each id associated with the appropriate with the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your list is not named. You can name it using `names(ids) <- ids`:

```
ids <- list(3,2,1)
names(ids) <- ids
parLapply(cl,ids,function(x) x)
$`3`
[1] 3

$`2`
[1] 2

$`1`
[1] 1
```